# xfce4-notifyd.service is not starting - how to troubleshoot

Tags: xfce

I have the problem that xfce4-notifyd.service is not starting when I login to my machine (Ubuntu 18.04.2 with XFCE).

I tried the solution mentioned here but still no change in behaviour: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12213

Currently I have to manually start it each time after login is finished - how can I debug / troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Run `journalctl -f` to follow logs and then try `notify-send test` from another terminal. If `notify-send` hangs and after a timeout you see the following error message in journalctl:

`org.freedesktop.Notifications[12345]: org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout`

The issue may be that you have `plasma-workspace` installed. If you don't need it anymore, remove it (`sudo apt-get remove plasma-workspace`), mind that this removes packages like `plasma-desktop`. Notifications should work again after removing this package.

See this [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1499743) for details.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me resolve a long-standing annoyance I had

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem:

Using "**journalctl**" I checked the logs again and saw this message that got my attention:

```
org.kde.knotifications: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout
```

So I checked  "**/usr/share/dbus-1/services**" for a file named "**org.kde.knotifications**".

I found the file and renamed it:

```
sudo mv org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service.bak
```

After a reboot everything works fine again